# Sleep() with moodle mail

Tags: moodle

When user registers, an email is sent to user after 20 seconds. Is this possible to code with sleep() in moodle.

```
sleep(20);
if (!send_confirmation_email($user)) {
    print_error('noemail','core_email');
}
```

Comment: Is the code above is the correct way to use sleep(). I tested, it was n't working. It was sending an email before 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The sleep will be fairly poor UX and block the session. An adhoc task is the right way to go as DerKanzler said.

As of https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-66925 you can run the adhoc tasks in keep alive mode and they will process continuously as a psuedo daemon:

```sh
php admin/cli/adhoc_task.php --keep-alive=60 --execute
```

If you still wanted the email to be sent roughly 20 seconds into the future, when you use the Task API to queue the task you can set the future time that it should run:

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Task_API#Set_a_task_to_run_at_a_future_time

Either way this sounds like a terrible idea to force a user to either way in their browser for 20 seconds, or to wait reloading their email client for 20 seconds. I'd strongly recommend against it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the 'hacky' way and patch some core files `sleep(seconds)` is indeed the easiest way to go.
If you are writing a plugin, you can have a look at the [Task API](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Task_API), especially at [defining AdHoc Tasks](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Task_API#Adhoc_task_usage). Though this will not execute until your cron job is fired. So you would have to lower your cron execution time limit. Besides that there is currently no option to do this with the moodle API.

Comment: You say it is not possible to code in moodle, but with cron job.

Comment: You can do it with cron a cron job. But the cron job only executes in a given interval which you specify. So if you cron job runs every 5 minutes, the eMail could take up to 5 minutes to get send. So your only option is to set the interval of your cron job to 20 seconds. The email will then be send in 20 seconds or less.

Comment: As of https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-66925 you can run the adhoc tasks in keep alive mode and they will process continuously as a psuedo daemon.

If you still wanted the email to be sent roughly 20 seconds into the future, when you use the Task API to queue the task you can set the future time that it should run: